# Vue3 composition API watch store value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I want to detect changes in a Vuex state value by watching it in a Vue component. I am currently using Vue 3 with the composition API. I've tried the following approach:

```js
setup(props) {
   const store = useStore();

   watch(store.getters.myvalue, function() {
      console.log('value changes detected');
   });

   return {
      myvalue: computed(() => store.getters.myvalue)
   }
},
```

But the `console.log()` will not be called when `myvalue` is changed.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you might need to **pass a function that returns** `myValue` **getter** instead of passing the `myValue` getter.

### Like so:

```js
setup(props) {
   const store = useStore();

   watch(() => store.getters.myvalue, function() {
      console.log('value changes detected');
   });

   return {
      myvalue: computed(() => store.getters.myvalue)
   }
},
```

### Here is a working example:

```js
const store = Vuex.createStore({
  state() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  getters: {
    count(state) {
      return state.count
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++
    }
  }
});

const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const store = Vuex.useStore();

    Vue.watch(() => store.getters.count, function() {
      console.log('value changes detected');
    });

    store.watch((state, getters) => getters.count, () => {
      console.log('value changes detected via vuex watch');
    })

    return {
      myvalue: Vue.computed(() => store.getters.count),
      change: ()=>{store.commit('increment')}
    }
  }
});

app.use(store);

app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="change"></button>
  {{myvalue}}
</div>
```

However there are more Vuex-specific ways to do this such as using Vuex `watch` (or `subscribe`). Link for examples and more details: [Watch for Vuex State changes!](https://dev.to/viniciuskneves/watch-for-vuex-state-changes-2mgj)

Comment: Is it recommended to write the computed in the return statement? asked in general.

Comment: it's just a matter of preference if you have a "small-enough" setup function, it's likely fine. As the the complexity rises, it makes for better housekeeping. Functionally, there's no difference.

Answer (score 5):

Let me answer your question in general way.

First of all you need to create store with state, getters, actions and mutations.

**Composition API**

You need to import store inside the component via

```
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
```

And initialise it inside component like this:

```
export default {
 setup(){
  const store = useStore();
 }
}
```

In order to watch the store changes you can use watchEffect(), do not forget to import it

```
import { watchEffect } from '@vue/runtime-core';

watchEffect(() => {
  // pretend you have a getData getter in store
  const data = store.getters.getData;
  if(data === null) return;
  console.log(data);
})
```

Moreover, you can use watch(), which is a bit older way

```
import { watch } from '@vue/runtime-core';

watch(
  // pretend you have a getData getter in store
  () => store.getters.getData,
  (val, oldVal) => console.dir({ val, oldVal})
)
```

In some cases you will have a warnings in console like this

```
Invalid watch source:  null A watch source can only be a getter/effect function, a ref, a reactive object, or an array of these types. 

`watch(fn, options?)` signature has been moved to a separate API. Use `watchEffect(fn, options?)` instead. `watch` now only supports `watch(source, cb, options?) signature.
```

**Option API**

Classic way to watch store changes is to create a function like this

```
data(){
 return {
  todo: null
 }
},
methods: {
 watchStore(){
  this.$store.watch(
    () => this.$store.getters.getData,
    data => this.todo = data
  )
 }
},
mounted(){
 this.watchStore();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `<script setup>` in **Vue 3** **composition API**. The solution would be like so:

Lets say you have the following getters in your store:

```
getters:{
  myValue(state){
    return state.myValue
  }
}
```

**Script setup:**

```
<script setup>
  import {watch} from 'vue'
  import {useStore} from 'vuex'

  const store = useStore()

  watch(() => store.getters.myValue, () => {
    console.log('value changes detected')
  })
</script>
```

**Note**: like **@Daniel** points out, to make it work, in `watch()` you need to pass a function (`() => store.getters.myValue`) that return `myValue` from the store getters. It can also be written like so:

```
watch(function(){return store.getters.myValue}, () => {
  console.log('value changes detected')
})
```